# Round a number and replace trailing zeros by spaces

Tags: regex, formatting, r, floating-point

**Goal**

From a number `x`, I would like a string of the rounded value at `n` decimals and replace each trailing zeros by a space.

**Examples**

Let `n = 4`

```
f(0.1, n=4)
[1] "0.1   " # 3 whitespace
f(0.1111999, n=4)
[1] "0.1112" # 0 whitespace
f(0.12, n=4)
[1] "0.12  " # 2 whitespace
f(0.1234, n=4)
[1] "0.1234" # 0 whitespace
```

**Current solution**

```
f <- function(x,n)
{
    s = sprintf(paste0("%.",n,"f"), x)
    for (i in 1:n)
    {
        s = gsub(
            paste0("0", paste0(rep("\\s",i-1),collapse=""),"$"),
            paste0(rep(" ",i), collapse=""),
            s
        )       
    }
    return(s)
}
```

It works fine but it is a little cumbersome. I suspect a better regex solution.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/12643391/2563804

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, `printf` already has a feature for padding data to a specific length, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/34346389/1201032. So you can do:

```
f <- function(x, n) {
  rounded_x <- as.character(round(x, n))
  num_lead_chars <- nchar(sub("[.].*", ".", rounded_x))
  sprintf("%-*s", n + num_lead_chars, rounded_x)
}
```

The function is vectorized for both inputs:

```
f(c(0.1, 0.1111999, 0.12, 0.1234), n = 4)
# [1] "0.1   " "0.1112" "0.12  " "0.1234"
f(0.1, n = 1:4)
# [1] "0.1"    "0.1 "   "0.1  "  "0.1   "
```